# How to implement a fixed "submit" button on a long form

Tags: usability, forms, user-expectation, long-forms

So I have a configuration menu and I want to add the "submit changes" button fixed to the bottom right corner of the screen. My issue is, my configuration menu options can expand past the bottom of the screen. I am afraid that some options will be hidden behind the fixed bottom rectangle as you can see in the image.

[image]

Is there a clear way to indicate to the user that there are more options below? Should I make the submit button on the bottom of the screen, but not fixed so the user must scroll to find it? Ideally, I'd like the user to know that there are more options while always having the "submit changes" button visible

Comment: What are the reasons for the sticky button?  You've found an obvious reason for not having it, but you haven't indicated why someone decided that it would be beneficial.

Comment: @RayButterworth Well, because the user can toggle between each menu 1-7 and then submit the changes all at once. For example, the user may get to this page, select menu 5, make a change, select menu 2, make a change and then hit submit. In this scenario, whether the user makes 1 change or 50, the submit button should be readily available at all times. I can't think of an alternative to this aside from a sticky button.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the length of your form. The submit button will be expected at the bottom of the form by most users, since this is a well known pattern.
So if you want your users to scroll down and see all the form fields this would be the way to go.

If your form is very long consider to split it into chunks.

If you need the button sticky for whatever reasons just choose a design that suggests that the bar with the button is in front of something you can achieve this for example by using a shadow effect on the sticky bar.

Answer (score 0):

The most natural solution would seem to be placing the Submit button below the form. That way you communicate the intent without needing any extra tricks.